# Facebook comments plugin data-href

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

We have a problem about facebook comments plugin. This problem occured 3 or 4 days ago.
Plugin Url: developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

In our plugin we are using "data-href" as custom url which is different from current url. This was working fine 3 or 4 days ago.

But today we realised that there is a bug for usage data-href. It seems plugin ignores custom url, just use current url as default behaviour.

**Page Url**: http://www.supplementler.com/urun/optimum-gold-standard-whey-2273-gr-608

**Custom Comment Url**: http://www.supplementler.com/urun/yorum-608

In fact this custom url has 782 comments:
graph.facebook.com/comments?id=**{Custom Comment Url}**

But in the page you can see it show only 1 comment. This is can be seen on the graph api like this:
graph.facebook.com/comments?id=**{Page Url}**

Our current usage of the plugin in our page **{Page Url}**:

Could anyone know any changes about facebook comments plugin lately? Or do we have any mistake about script or something else?

Comment: Now we see that problem is fixed somehow.